# Draggable modal dialog with embedded flash video does not allow video to be played

Tags: jquery, flash, firefox, google-chrome, draggable

I have a modal dialog with a flash video on it and I'm using the jQuery draggable plugin to make it draggable. On Chrome, it doesn't let me play the video (when I click on the play button it does nothing, though I can drag the div around if I hold down the mouse). On Firefox, the video will play, but the mouse gets "stuck" to the div and the div follows it around. Is there some easy way to prevent dragging on the flash div?

Answer (score 0):

Add a "handle" to the div, this will allow the user to drag the div but only when they click on that area. Just place a element in the div and then specify it as the handle for that draggable.

Initialize a draggable with the handle option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ handle: 'h2' });
```

Get or set the handle option, after init.

```
// getter
var handle = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "handle" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "handle", 'h2' );
```

Documentation from http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-handle

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("#openDialog").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 zIndex: -1,
 resizable: true,
 draggable: true,
 height: 'auto',
 width: '800',
```

}